# Creating a 'df' that has a which and runif function

Tags: r

I am having trouble here with my code. I want to create a new `df1`that (a) has the random number generated within a selected range, and also lists the [row,col] of a number from another data frame `Q_Sheet` closes to it.  Any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
df1<- data.frame(T4=c(runif(n=1,min=5,max=6),
                 which(Q_Sheet$T_degC==df1[1,1],arr.ind=T))
```

`V_Sheet`

```
Amino_acids Protein_Length_Ang Length_no_ratio Corrected_aa aa_freq T_degC
4              7                1.75         1.24e-12        1.60   66.30  
8              NA                NA          6.79e-11       5.81   **68.29**
```

Code I am applying to extract the [row, col] of 68.29:

`t4<-runif(n=1,min=60,max=70)`

`tmp4<-abs(V_Sheet-t4)`

`result4<-which(tmp4==min(tmp4),arr.ind=TRUE)`

`R4<- data.frame(T4=c(t4,toStrong(result4)))`

`Q_Sheet`

```
Temp_1 Temp_2 Temp_degC
3.2     2.7      3.4
4.5     3.9      5.1
```

Desired output `df1`

```
T4
5.1
[2,3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val<- runif(n=1,min=5,max=6)
tmp <- abs(Q_Sheet - val)
result <- which(tmp == min(tmp), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

If you want to store the output in a dataframe.

```
df1<- data.frame(T4 = c(val, toString(result)))
df1
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out.

Comment: I am getting an error: " Error in Ops.data.frame(Q_Sheet,T456_df): "-" only defined for equally-sized data frames

Comment: Are you using my code as it is? It seems you are putting the value `val` in a dataframe in which case you have to do `val$column_name`.

Comment: I made an error. You rock. It has worked. I made a bit of a typo.. I have been working on this issue for two weeks.

Comment: I have another question. if I ran `result <- which(tmp==min(tmp),arr.ind=TRUE) ` and get a data frame output of int[0,1:2], how does this arise? Your code worked, but I applied it to something else, and received that output. The only way I could get something-- a column location for a close number -- was to do something like `df$col`.

Comment: The output depends on the input data that you have.

Comment: I updated the original post. Take a look at `V_Sheet` and the code I am trying to use to extract `[row,col]` for `68.29`